# What is the correct way to include PHP functions in Joomla for use in articles?

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I am using Joomla 2.5 and DirectPHP. I can run PHP code in an article just fine. I would like to include a library of PHP functions to be available for use in all articles.  What is the best way to include the function library?

I tried including (with require) from the template's index.php and even putting the functions directly in index.php, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206708/how-do-i-include-a-file-of-php-functions-in-a-joomla-template).  None of the functions are defined in the article. A test with variables and global variables also finds them undefined in the article.

I then created a custom HTML module with the PHP functions that I then used in my template, but they are still undefined in the article. Oddly enough, if I try and declare the function again in the article I get "Cannot redeclare...". How can the function be both undefined, not re-defineable?

I also tried using a namespace to define and use my functions. Same result.
Code in my custom html module:

```
<?php
namespace c6;
function testit5()
    {
    echo "hello world 5";
    }
?>
```

Code in my article:

```
<?php

namespace c6;

testit5();
?>
```

Result:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function c6\testit5() in /home/testsite/www/www/c6test/plugins/content/DirectPHP/DirectPHP.php(58) : eval()'d code on line 5

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! My problem was the *order* Joomla processes things.  Apparently the article is processed first, then the template.  So my code using the function executed before the module that defined the function was executed.  (When I got the "cannot redeclare" error, it was coming from the template, not the article.) I moved my loadposition from the template to the article and it works.

Answer (score 0):

go to,

```
Login to admin -> Extensions Menu -> Module Manager -> Create New Module -> Choose Custom HTML
```

and create you own module and add php functions.